# Center aligning a single letter inside a div

Tags: css

For a web forum I'm building, I want to use the first letter from users' usernames as an avatar (for those who haven't uploaded an avatar yet).

To accomplish this, I'm taking the first letter, capitalizing it, and then drawing a circle around it such that the letter appears perfectly in the middle of the said circle.

I've used CSS to do this. Look at the results:

[image]

And here's how it looks in browsers that don't support `border-radius` (e.g. Opera Mini):

[image]

Note that I'm OK with squared results for browsers where 'border-radius' doesn't work.

---

**The problem:** The letter is not perfectly center aligned (vertically and horizontally) inside the shape.

For instance, if I increase or decrease the font-size respectively, here's what happens:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I ensure that the letter remains center aligned horizontally and vertically within the div *regardless of font size*?

Please provide an illustrative example, preferably with well-support CSS 2.1 attributes since a substantial number of clients I have to cater are Opera Mini browsers with thin CSS3 or JS support.

---

Here's how I tried doing it:

```css
.av_btn {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="av_btn" style="border: 1px #1947D1 solid;width:22px;height:22px;">
  <b>M</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems (at least) part of your issue is caused by the use of inline styles coupled with CSS styles.

The inline styles of `height` and `width` are hardcoded to fixed pixel values. While the CSS values don't define a `font-size`, so it's using the browser's, or inherited, font size). And to get the desired result we need to have the `height`, `width`, `line-height`, and `font-size` match up.

I'd recommend moving all the styles to a single source - which could be either inline or CSS. I'll go with CSS for the solution below.

I think the best solution would be to match the `line-height`, `width` and `height` properties to a value using `em` units. For example `1.7em` units.

With this setup the `font-size` can be changed to nearly anything and the letter will be placed in the center of the element.

Here's an example:

```css
.av_btn {
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  width: 1.7em;
  height: 1.7em;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px #1947D1 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="av_btn">
  <b>M</b>
</div>
```

And here's an example showing how it scales with font size.

```js
var size = document.getElementById("font-size");
var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");

size.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  var fontSize = event.target.value;
  avatar.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
})
```

```css
.av_btn {
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  width: 1.7em;
  height: 1.7em;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px #1947D1 solid;
}
```

```html
<input id="font-size" type="range" min="16" max="100" value="16" /> 

<div class="av_btn" id="avatar">
  <b>M</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Another question: What's the advantage of using `display: inline-flex;`, `align-content: center;` and `justify-content: center;` instead of  `text-align: center;` and `display: inline-block;`? Both approaches seem to render precisely the same results.